# CSS font-size: Does it matter what kind of unit you use?

Tags: css, font-size

Apparently, points (pt) shouldn’t be used on web, only in print media. Pixels (px) should be used if you want a pixel-perfect representation of your site. Percent (%) and ems (em) works almost equally, and should be used if you want your site to be scalable when zooming etc.

Five minutes ago, I wrote these few lines of code, and tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE and iPhone 5.

```
<html>
<p style="font-size:16px;">Dette er en test</p>
<p style="font-size:100%;">Dette er en test</p>
<p style="font-size:1em;">Dette er en test</p>
<p style="font-size:12pt;">Dette er en test</p>
</html>
```

What happened was that all the paragraphs remains equal sized when I zoomed in and out. So does it really matter what kind of unit you use?

Comment: Pixels aren't great for visually impaired people using older browsers. Not sure about the others but IE at least wouldn't enlarge pixel sized text meaning a low vision person couldn't benefit from the larger text. The issue isn't zooming, it's when you go into your internet options and set the font size.

Comment: [Font size in percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) (very old post but I am sure it explains the same.)

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question, the phrase "does it really matter" sollicits debate/discussion IMO.

Comment: Zooming is not the same as changing the base font size.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a great article on this: http://alistapart.com/article/howtosizetextincss

His conclusion:

> Our task was to find a way to size text that allows designers to retain accurate control of typography, without sacrificing the user’s ability to adjust his or her reading environment. We tested various units across common browsers. Sizing text and line-height in ems, with a percentage specified on the body (and an optional caveat for Safari 2), was shown to provide accurate, resizable text across all browsers in common use today. This is a technique you can put in your kit bag and use as a best practice for sizing text in CSS that satisfies both designers and readers.
>
> Ems can be tricky to work with, especially when nesting elements deeply, as it can be hard to keep track of the maths. However, commenting your style sheets well and styling elements from the body inwards can keep things easier to follow. This more complex example and its accompanying style sheet demonstrate how to size nested elements using the body as the starting point.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

the em unit is the newest and upcoming standard for font sizes on the web, but in practice, the percent unit seems to provide a more consistent and accessible display for users.

When client settings have changed, percent text scales at a reasonable rate, allowing you to preserve readability, accessibility and visual design.

So I suggest you to use percent.

**[Here](http://pxtoem.com/)** you can take a look at conversions, hope it help.

Comment: em is really old, rem is the new one.

Comment: I should take a look at rem, never used it.

Comment: here: http://caniuse.com/#search=rem there is some explanation and compatibility table

Comment: If you've never heard of rem, where did you get the idea that em was "the newest and upcoming standard"?

Comment: simply because px and percent are the older one. And em has been added later, so its newer then others. Rem has been added with css3 and it works exactly like em but it do not inherit anymore from a previous setted font-size but is always based to the root percent (ie: 62.5%). So in my opinion it is always better to use percent for font-size. No rem.

Comment: And I sad **never used**, not never heard.

Comment: no one knows everything, its ok to miss one or two new elements. Dont worry

Comment: But you can even use both: ie: `p { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1.6rem; }` is cascade so if a browser do not read rem it will bypass it. Browsers that support will read px first and rem then overriding px.

Answer (score 0):

Different units are useful in different situations. To know when to use which unit you have to know what they do. This is pretty well explained [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length#Units), or if you prefer [in the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) (for %, see below).

Here's the quote from MDN on the unit types you mention:

> **em**
>    This unit represents the calculated font-size of the element. If used on the font-size property itself, it represents the inherited font-size of the element.
>
> **px**
>   Relative to the viewing device.
>    For screen display, typically one device pixel (dot) of the display.
>    For printers and very high resolution screens one CSS pixel implies multiple device pixels, so that the number of pixel per inch stays around 96.
>
> **pt**
>   One point (which is 1/72 of an inch).

Percentage is the odd one out, has [its own MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/percentage).

> Many length properties use percentages, such as width, margin and padding. Percentages can also be seen in font-size, where the size of the text is directly related to the size of its parent.

Or its own subsection [in the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#percentages):

> Percentage values are always relative to another value, for example a length. Each property that allows percentages also defines the value to which the percentage refers. The value may be that of another property for the same element, a property for an ancestor element, or a value of the formatting context (e.g., the width of a containing block). When a percentage value is set for a property of the root element and the percentage is defined as referring to the inherited value of some property, the resultant value is the percentage times the initial value of that property.

So "yes", it matters which you choose, they each can have *different* effects in different circumstances (regardless of the fact that they can also often lead to the *same* result).